# Apply a function to each sub-cell of a cell in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a cell `C` in Matlab of dimension `mx1`, e.g. `m=3`

```
C={{1 2 3} {4 5 6} {7 8 9 10}}
```

Then I have a function `g` written in a separate m-file

```
function D=g(C{i},a,b)
...
end
```

that takes any sub-cell `C{i}` of `C` and using some other parameters `a` and `b` gives a vector `D` of dimension `fx1`.

I want to apply the function `g` to each sub-cell of `C` and assemble the obtained `fx1` vectors in a matrix `fxm` without using loops. I have seen the command `cellfun` but I don't know how to make it working with a function written by myself. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple.  First make a handle to the function where the only input is the cell array:

```
h = @(x) D(x, a, b);
```

Here, `x` would be a cell from the cell array.  Also, I'm going to assume that `a` and `b` are already defined in your workspace.  After, just do this:

```
out = cellfun(h, C, 'uni', 0);
```

The first argument is a handle to the function, which we've already defined.  The next parameter is the cell array you want to operate on and apply the function `h` to every cell in your array.  You need to specify the `uni=0` flag because the output is **non-uniform**.  Because your function outputs a vector per cell, this is mandatory.  If your function outputted a single value, then this declaration of `uni=0` is not required.

Alternatively, you can do this in a loop... which is what `cellfun` ultimately performs:

```
out = cell(numel(C), 1);
for idx = 1 : numel(C)
    out{idx} = D(C{idx}, a, b);
end
```

To me, the second option is more suitable for those who aren't used to using `cellfun`.

Comment: @user3285148 three things,
1) You don't need to define an anonymous function you can do it inline `out = cellfun(@(x) g(x, a, b), C, 'uni', 0);`.
2) If all your inputs are cells of the same size, then you can say `out = cellfun(@g, C, a, b, 'uni', 0);`.
3) If `a` and `b` are matrices of the same size as C, you can convert the inputs to cells, `out = cellfun(@g, C, num2cell(a), num2cell(b), 'uni', 0);`.

Comment: @user1543042 I split it up as an inline function to make it clear on what I was doing. 2) I interpreted them as constants hence the anonymous wrapper. 3) they're probably not matrices..then again I can't be sure.

Comment: For (1) it's just a style preference, and for (2) and (3) you're probably right. I just wanted to make sure OP knew about some little tricks. I thought that your answer was very good.

Comment: @user1543042 ah I see! Fair enough! Thanks for the kudos :)